# Maximize the unused space of a picture

Tags: diagrams

I would like to add a picture in the journal at [www.overleaf.com](http://www.overleaf.com) with compiler pdfLaTeX TeX Live version 2022 with the following code.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1.5 in]{dual_armed_cluster_tool.JPG}
    \caption{A Serial Dual Armed Cluster Tool with $\qvec{m}= [1,1,1,1]$.}
    \label{fig:Dual_Armed_Cluster_Tool}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The existing result is:

[image: existing]

There are a lot of unused white space in the picture. Is there any way to make it becomes like the following picture?

[image: expectation]

Comment: You could check out the `wrapfig` or the `wrapstuff` package.

Comment: You are already in two column mode, although 1.5in is only about half the column width.  You could just make it bigger so that the embedded text is not totally illegible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I was curious, here is a wrapfig solution.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only
\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{1.5in}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1.5in]{example-image}
    \caption{A Serial Dual Armed Cluster Tool with ${m}= [1,1,1,1]$.}
    \label{fig:Dual_Armed_Cluster_Tool}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @John!